# Remove empty files from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have 500 gb data set in S3 bucket, where we have some empty files, need to remove the empty files is there a better than copying to a linux machine and running the `find` cmd to delete the empty files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know which files are empty, you could request [S3 inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html). It is provided once a day or week in a CSV format. One of its fields is:

> Size – Object size in bytes.

Thus, having the inventory file, you will be able to very efficiently identify, and then remove, empty files from your bucket.

Comment: alternatively the listobjects apis provide the size as well.

Comment: @luk2302 Yes, that's true. Guess it really depends of how much files there is in `500 gb` bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I mounted the bucket on to an ec2 instance using s3fs and ran the empty file/dir check, this method was more convenient.